# C3P0 rawStatementOperation usage

Tags: java-8, connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am using C3P0 connection pooling in my project.

I came across below Method in C3P0ProxyStatement,

```
C3P0ProxyStatement pStmt = (C3P0ProxyStatement) stmt;
pStmt.rawStatementOperation(..,..);
```

Please help me with below doubts ,

What is the use of rawStatementOperation in this c3p0 ?

Why does this statement takes reflect API method as parameter?

Using it will it impact performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People rarely use this API recently, preferring the JDBC4 standard `unwrap(...)` to get access to native Statements and Connections.

Yes, this c3p0-specific API is reflective (and it is a bit safer than unwrapping, as c3p0 will track and try to clean up some JDBC resources that might be returned). The cost of a reflective method call is high relative to an ordinary method call, but negligible relative to the cost of database operations. It won't meaningfully impact performance.